# Count two or more repeated characters in a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

```
-----------
ID | Value
-----------
1  | AAAA
2  | ABCD
3  | AADC
4  | ABBD
```

I am trying to figure out how to return the number of times a string occurs in each of the Value.

So, if I want to count of time 'A' and 'B'appears, the sql statement will return like this:

```
-------------------
ID | Value | Count
------------------- 
1  | AAAA  |   0 
2  | ABCD  |   1 
3  | AADC  |   0 
4  | ABBD  |   2 
5  | ABBB  |   3 
6  | AABB  |   3 
7  | AAAB  |   3
```

Is there any way to do this? I do not want to use php, vb, etc. Just MySQL

Comment: I don't understand your expected results. Why are some 2 and 3?

Comment: Are you looking for A, B or both? The count column you have does not appear to be correct

Comment: I am looking for both, A and B. First Step, it will search both A and B. When there a other A or B, it will count. So when the value is AABC, it will count 2 (AB and A)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this mate:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Value,
    LENGTH(REPLACE(Value, 'A', '')) 'count_a',
    LENGTH(REPLACE(Value, 'B', '')) 'count_b'
FROM
    your_table;
```

or this one:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Value,
    LENGTH(REPLACE(Value, IF(LENGTH(REPLACE(Value, 'A','')) = 3, 'A', 'B'), '')) 'Count',
FROM
    your_table;
```

This one is based on the given expected result

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to count the values and then combine the result. I believe something like this will work for you.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6775e/1)

```
SELECT 
    id,
    value,    
    ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(value)
            - LENGTH(REPLACE(value, "A", "")) 
        ) / LENGTH("A")        
    ) AS count    
FROM chars
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    id,
    value,    
    ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(value)
            - LENGTH(REPLACE(value, "B", "")) 
        ) / LENGTH("B")        
    ) AS count    
FROM chars
```